# Does Convolution Neural Network need normalized input?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, normalization, convolution

I have trained a Convolution Neural Network, after comparing two normalizations,

I found that simple minus mean and divided by standard variance is better than scaling into [0, 1], it seems that the interval of input value is unnecessary in [0, 1] with sigmoid function.

Does anybody could explain about it?

Comment: can you explain more or add a reference to exactly what model you are implementing?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a NN using logistic regression, then you are correct that a suitable sigmoid function (or [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) in this context) will give you a [0, 1] range from your original inputs.

However, the logistic function works best when the inputs are in a small range on either side of zero - so, for example, your input to the logistic function might be [-3, +3].

By *rescaling* your data to [0, 1] first, you would flatten out any underlying distribution and move all of your data to the positive side of zero, which is not what the logistic function expects. So you *will* get a worse result than by *normalising* (i.e. subtract mean and divide by standard deviation, as you said) because that normalisation step takes account of the variance in the original distribution and makes sure that the mean is zero so you get both positive and negative data input to the logistic function.

In your question, you said "comparing two normalisations" - I think you are misunderstanding what "normalisation" means and actually comparing [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29) with rescaling, which is different.

Comment: Thanks Roger, your are right, I misunderstood the term "normalization" and "rescaling". I'm confused that whether normalizing input data of convolution layer, all hidden layers else are preceded a sigmoid function individually, and the last layer is a softmax function, I'm not sure whether rescaling input into [0, 1] range is necessary.